# cordova apk jumps to previous view automatically

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, apache-cordova

I have an Apache Cordova apk developed with jQuery Mobile that when I send request to server and get data from it, if it returns 200 I will change pagecontainer to another page. the problems is sometimes when i change pagecontainer after 1 second it automatically jumps to the previous page with no reasonable reason.
can anybody give me a clue about that?

thanks a lot

here is the code

```
$("#login").click(function() {
    $.ajax(serverUrl + "/login", {
        data: {
            email: userEmail,
            password: userPassword
        },
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data) {
                //OK, Welcome!
                $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#welcomePage");
            },
        }
    });
});
```

but when i have the following which is almost as same the previous one on $(documnet).ready everything looks fine

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax(serverUrl + "/enter", {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": userSavedToken
        },
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data) {
                //OK, Welcome Back!
                $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#welcomePage");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this problem did not happen in ripple and genymotion, it's just in the real android devices!

Comment: Are you using above both code in your application?

Comment: @Homen, yes. i use both.

Comment: ready function code need to run only at starting of the application?